# Q&A-style answering bug where "40mins between questions" hidden by answer box

Tags: bug, design

When posting a Q&A question, the warning that you can't post within 40mins of previous post is hidden by the "answer" portion of submission.  When the answer section is there (i.e. the box has been ticked) and a post is submitted, the page refreshes with seemingly no error message.  Once I unticked the "answer own question" tick box, the error message about rapid posting came up.

Ironically, I can also not post the bug report here, until 40 mins is up ;).